# Wrong data obtained from MySQL database with JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, database

My PHP script obtains a list of unique users and their last entries in my database. My goal is to take this list of users and use it in my javascript code.

I've checked my PHP code and it prints out the list of users. However, when I use JSON to get the data over to javascript, an entirely different column of data is shown!

I can even remove json_encode from my php and remove that column of data from my SQL query and it still shows up. I just started using PDO so I think thats the culprit. Any help?

PHP Code Snippet:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Get all unique users last event.
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM events WHERE Id in (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM events GROUP BY UserName)");

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if($stmt->execute(array($_GET['Region']))){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        //If most recent event is login or enter, user is currently logged in
        if($row['Type'] == "logout" || $row['Type'] == "login"){
            array_push($userList, $row['UserName']);
            $currentUserCount++;
        }
    }
}
echo("Number of Users Logged in: " . $currentUserCount);
echo json_encode($userList);

}
```

JS Code Snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var userList = [];

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON('/Statistics/process.php', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key){
                userList.push(key);
                document.write(key + "<br />");
            });
        });

        console.log(userList);

    });

</script>
```

Extra Info:

My DB has this set up:

Id | UUID | UserName | Region | Type | Time |

I am sending the UserName data but receiving the Region data in js.

Comment: you CAN NOT log the expected results outside of ajax success callback, it is asynchronous

Comment: What is the reason behind `array($_GET['Region'])` in your `execute` method? It does not look like you are using it in your SQL.

Comment: I have a webpage with an image map that when clicked, adds a query to my .php script. An example of this is I click the image map, and it leads the user to a webpage called process.php?Region=RegionNameHere. Then RegionNameHere is used in the SQL Query to obtain a list of users exclusive in that Region

Comment: Can you post an example of what `console.log(data);` inside the `$.getJSON` method displays. Also, post an example of `print_r($userList, true);` before `json_encode()` call.

Comment: print_r($userList, true); prints out a large list of peoples names. Ex. ["John Doe", "Ronald Mcdonald", "George Washington"]. console.log(data) prints out an associate array of the region names with values of 0 for all of them. Ex. [key: 'value', Region1: 0, Region2: 0, Region3: 0] I would like to emphasize that I can remove json_encode and data is still being transferred.

Comment: To add to this, I even completely removed the PHP code snippet completely (just to see what would happen). The Region data is still there. What on earth could cause this?

Comment: Try changing `SELECT * FROM` to something specific like `SELECT UserName FROM`. If that does not change the results then try removing `array($_GET['Region'])`.